# Create svn repository on CentOS 5.5

Tags: linux, svn, repository

I want to create a svn repository on CentOS 5.5 and connect to it with TortoiseSVN.

I tried many ways. The last one was this (logged in as root):

```
# mkdir /home/me/myrepo/
# svnadmin create /home/me/myrepo/
```

Then I edited (as many posts suggested /home/me/myrepo/conf/svnserve.conf) and added

```
 anon-access = read
 auth-access = write
 realm = My First Repository
 password-db = passwd
```

to [general].

The problem is that when I try to do the checkout on the computer I want to access it from (or any other for that matter) the following things happen:

1. Ask for username (correct)
2. Ask for password (again correct)

I insert both correctly (tried with 3 different accounts)

3. Asking for username again (...)
4. Asking for password again (not so logical...)
5. Failing to connect with message (the connection was closed unexpectedly)

[image]

Comment: be more specific about your distro (debian, centos, gentoo, rhel, suse, ubuntu, fedora, etc...)

Comment: Did you install PuTTY and have a default hostname set on that computers?

Comment: I have putty, the machine is a vps with lots of sites so no default.

Comment: Does [it](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#sshclosed) help?

Answer (score 1):

Look there, this website has good tutorial :

[Server-World.info](http://server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=subversion) You might have missed something while configuring the server. So look there and check to see if you didn't miss something.

You can change the distro looking in the bottom of left menu. and change to the next step of the tuto using the right menu.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The tutorial is good +1 but I was looking for ssh. Not http :)